# Calculating a decimal number to data type TIME

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on a school project right now that requires me to generate some tables with the use of SQL from a database. We have 15 questions, and the goal is to answer all of them and show the query you used to generate your result.

The question we are answering right now is: what is the arrival time of the flight that flies between Amsterdam and New York, the date of this flight is 15-04-2018.

we are using an ERD that I build using some information obtained from the assignment.

This is what we came up with.  There is one small mistake in this, which is that the IATA_Code is not an integer but a varchar (sorry that some of the names are in dutch).

[image]

Now, the problem is that when I try to add something to `vertrektijd`, which means starting time, it doesn't work. I get a number like 6,2 hours which needs to be converted to hours, minutes, seconds and then added to the starting time. Whatever I try, it doesn't work

I've tried to use functions like `date_add`, `dateadd` and many more things. But I seem to fail at converting the 6,25 hours to an actual time which makes the whole thing fail

```
select distinct(DATEADD(hour, sector.Afstand/vliegtuig.Snelheid, vlucht.vertrektijd) AS DateAdd)
from sector, vlucht, vliegtuig
where vlucht.datum = '2018-04-15'
and vlucht.VluchtNr = '2513'
and sector.afstand IN (SELECT sum(sector.afstand) AS totale_afstand 
FROM  vlucht, routesector,sector
where routesector.Vlucht_VluchtNr = vlucht.VluchtNr 
AND routesector.Sector_SectorNr = sector.SectorNr 
and vlucht.datum = '2018-04-15'
AND vlucht.VluchtNr = '2513'
group by routesector.Vlucht_VluchtNr
order by totale_afstand);
```

So what I want this to do is to add the result of sector.afstand/vliegtuig.snelheid in hours to vlucht.vertrektijd

But whatever I try I can't seem to get it to work. I never used StackOverflow before as I like to solve problems on my own, but right now I don't know what to do.

For the amazing person who can make sense of all of this, would you mind explaining to me what I did wrong so I could solve it and move to the next assignment?

thanks for the attention :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that duration of a flight is in hours (can be fractional), you can convert it into minutes by multiplying by 60 and then use dateadd:

```
declare @t datetime
set @t='1/1/2019 3:15'
set @t=dateadd(MI, 6.25*60, @t)
print @t

Jan  1 2019  9:30AM
```